# Message Map MFC: Inheriting multiple message maps

Tags: c++, mfc, afx

I am using MFC100, VS2010, MDI.

I am over ridding the basic functionality of CPreviewView.

I want it to act very similar to my CMyView(Which is a CView)

CMyView and CMyPreviewView are not in the same class inheritance paths.

So I want to inherit both the CPreviewView message map and CMyView message maps. Currently, it only inherits the CPreviewView message maps.

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMyPreviewView, CPreviewView)
    //{{AFX_MSG_MAP(CMyPreviewView)
    ON_COMMAND(AFX_ID_PREVIEW_CLOSE, OnPreviewClose)
    ON_COMMAND(AFX_ID_PREVIEW_PRINT, OnPreviewPrint)
    ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI(ID_WINDOW_NEW, OnUpdateWindowNew)
    //}}AFX_MSG_MAP
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

Any Ideas? I saw things like

```
ALT_MSG_MAP(UINT msgMapID)
```

But that is only for ATL. I could copy and paste my entire CMyView message map, but that is really messy being that is has 300+ handlers.

Comment: I seem to recall reading an article about "multiple inheritance" for MFC a long time ago and it wasn't pretty. Any reason you can't just use CMyView and embed CMyPreviewView inside it? Should be simple enough.

Comment: CMyPreviewView and CMyView are completly different classes. 
"CMyPreviewView->CPreviewView->CScrollView...->CView" and "CMyView->CView" They cant be in the same inheritance path.. I just want them to have the same command handlers. without copying and pasting and maintaining 2 places.

Comment: Not what I meant, but seems you found your solution so nm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the message map into a separate .h file and `#include` it into both classes.

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMyPreviewView, CPreviewView)
    //{{AFX_MSG_MAP(CMyPreviewView)
    ON_COMMAND(AFX_ID_PREVIEW_CLOSE, OnPreviewClose)
    ON_COMMAND(AFX_ID_PREVIEW_PRINT, OnPreviewPrint)
    ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI(ID_WINDOW_NEW, OnUpdateWindowNew)

#include "SharedViewMessageMap.h"

    //}}AFX_MSG_MAP
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

Answer (score 1):

Per the section *CWnd and Message Maps* on [TN016: Using C++ Multiple Inheritance with MFC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/62x3wzxy.aspx), it is not possible to make the MFC message map work with multiple inheritance work with more than one type derived from `CWnd` as any `CWnd`-derived base must be the left-most one in its inheritance. Since `CView` derives from `CWnd`, you cannot multiply inherit from those classes.

In order to avoid direct duplication of your code, it's possible you may be able to refactor the code you wish to share into some sort of mixin, perhaps using composition or CRTP.

Comment: I'm sorry, i think i made this confusing. I am not using "class Multiple inheritance" ,,I was referring to "message map inheritance". I want CMyPreviewView class to have 2 message maps, CPreview, and CMyView message maps.

Comment: Are you saying I may be able to move the command handlers to a separate/single place? and refer to it in both places? like a macro/define?